# if $ h(x) = x\cdot g(x)$ and it is known that $ g(3) = 5$, and $g′(3) = 2$ , find $ h'(3)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is an example in my book. (James Stewart Calculus 7E pg 132) A solution is given, but I don't understand it, even after looking at it over and over. I know I am supposed make use of the product rule $[(fg)′ = fg′ + gf′]$, but I guess I need it spelled out for me like a small child because I don't get it
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$h'(x) = g(x) + xg'(x).$$
Thus
$$h'(3) = g(3) + 3g'(3) = 5 + 3\cdot 2 = 11.$$
Notice that your function $h =fg$ where $f=x$ and so $f'=1$.

Comment: Why does f′ equal 1? if x is 3, isn't its derivative 0?

Comment: why does h′x not equal x′g(x) + xg′(x)  ?

Comment: It does but the derivative of $f(x)=x$ is simply equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $h'(x) = g(x) + xg'(x)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I can solve from there, but I don't understand how you got there from 

h(x) = xg(x)

Comment: I still don't understand. I have never had problems with composition of functions before but this makes absolutely no sense to me

Comment: $f(x) = x$. Do you get it now....?

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do, not sure where I'm going wrong. 

To find the answer I should be doing (xg(x))′ = x*g′(x) + g(x)*x′  

right?  

so plugging things in I get = 3*2 + 5*0 , the last one being x′, where derivative of 3 would be 0

Comment: in the solutions I am seeing it seems to me that an x′ is missing. But I know that my understanding of the problem must be wrong